# Put data in input type from clicked date

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have `index.php` and `add.php`. My question is when I click on a link of day in `index.php`, then go to `add.php` and store in input date the value of clicked day

index.php

```
<td><a href ="add.php"><?php $date1=date('y-m-d');echo $date1;?></a></td>

<td><a href ="add.php"><?php $date2=date('y-m-d' ,strtotime("+1day"));echo $date2;?></a></td>
```

add.php

```
<input type="date" name"date" >
```

I need that when click on date ,auto store in input without filling

Comment: can u share , in which format date is printed in index.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the the `strtotime("+1 day")` to the `$_GET` parameter, and extract it and pass it onto the value on your second page. Something like this for your `index.php`

```
<td><a href="add.php?date=<?php echo time(); ?>"><?php echo date('y-m-d'); ?></a></td>
<td><a href="add.php?date=<?php echo strtotime("+1 day"); ?>"><?php echo date('y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day")); ?></a></td>
```

And in `add.php` you can fetch that value with `$_GET['date']`, which you can convert to a date with `date("Y-m-d", $_GET['date'])`, which you add in as a value to the input.

I've added the time into a ternary operator, so that you avoid getting *Undefined index* warnings. By default, it's set to be the date of today.

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo (!empty($_GET['date']) ? date("Y-m-d", $_GET['date']) : date("Y-m-d")); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you for describing my answer in more detail.

Comment: Tank you very much all

Comment: @ubuntu If any answer works for you , you should do upvote and accept answer.

Comment: @hiren didn't mean to steal your answer! Had to go afk midway through typing up my answer, that's why mine came after :p I've upvoted your answer too, it's basically the same thing ;)

Comment: yaa , no problem. @Qirel

Answer (score 2):

index.php

```
<td><a href ="add.php?date=<?php $date1=date('y-m-d');echo $date1;?>"><?php echo $date1;?></a></td>

<td><a href ="add.php?date="<?php $date2=date('y-m-d' ,strtotime("+1day"));echo $date2;?>><?php echo $date2;</a></td>
```

By clicking on one of above `<a>` , it will redirect to `add.php` with get parameter `date`.

In `add.php` , this date varible can be retrived using php and can be stored to input element.

add.php

```
<input type="date" name="date" value=""<?php echo $_GET['day']; ?>"">
```

output of `<?php echo $_GET['day']; ?>` should be in formate 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: @ubuntu can you check this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In index.php

```
<a href="add.php?day=tuesday">Tuesday</a>
<a href="add.php?day=wednesday">Wednesday</a>
```

then, in add.php

```
<?php $day = $_GET['day']; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Pinkthank you to answer me but i dont need tuesday,wednesday becuse its dynamic date